# Divide multiple variable values by a specific value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization

I'm trying to pull something that is simple but can't seem to get my head over it. My data looks like this

### |Assay|Sample|Number|

|A|1|10|

|B|1|25|

|C|1|30|

|A|2|45|

|B|2|65|

|C|2|8|

|A|3|10|

|B|3|81|

|C|3|12|

What I need to do is to divide each "Number" value for each sample by the value of the respective assay A. That is, for sample 1, I would like to have 10/10, 25/10 and 30/10. Then for sample 2, I would need 45/45, 65/45 and 8/45 and so on with the rest of the samples.
I have already tried doing:

```
mutate(Normalised = Number/Number[Assay == "A"])
```

as suggested in another post but the results are not correct.

Any help would be great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
df <- data.frame(Assay=rep(c('A','B','C'),3),
                 Sample=rep(1:3,each=3),
                 Number=c(10,25,30,45,65,8,10,81,12))
df <- df %>% 
        group_by(Sample) %>% 
        arrange(Assay) %>% 
        mutate(Normalised=Number/first(Number)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        arrange(Sample)
```

gives out

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Assay Sample Number Normalised
  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A          1     10      1    
2 B          1     25      2.5  
3 C          1     30      3    
4 A          2     45      1    
5 B          2     65      1.44 
6 C          2      8      0.178
7 A          3     10      1    
8 B          3     81      8.1  
9 C          3     12      1.2
```

**Note:** I added `arrange(Assay)` just to make sure "A" is always the first row within each group. Also, `arrange(Sample)` is there just to get the output in the same order as it was but it doesn't really need to be there if you don't care about the display order.

Comment: You are right. It was not possible to identify the rows in your code for me .Sorry!

Comment: @wernor

  Thank you very very much, it worked perfectly! I can finally get this out of my head, I'm literally jumping around the office.